# Deploying Java app with OpenCV library

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to deploy my java application that uses opencv library, but when I run it from another computer I get an error message saying:

```
libopencv_java310.so: libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but I have the ffmpeg installed correctly from official repo with no errors occurred but it still didn't install "libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56".

Suspicions:
Is it possible that the machine that I've compiled opencv library got a different directory pointing to ffmpeg, and when I try to run the java app from another computer the pre-compiled opencv library doesn't find ffmpeg?

PS: actually before getting the error from ffmpeg I got an error saying that "libjpeg.so.8" ins't installed but I "fixed" linking with "libjpeg.so" that I had.

Comment: Is the opencv jar + native folder in the project that you want to deploy?

Comment: yes. opencv-310.jar, the 'lib' directory copied from the opencv's build and "mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar" necessary for my project are all included in the project's directory that I run with the command `java -jar -Djava.library.path=lib myproject.jar`.

Comment: okay what about the native folder? I mean the x86 and x64 folder that you specified in the native path, are they in lib folder as well or locally on the machine?

Comment: Do you mean when I build opencv? or the native directory of my project? either way I saw nothing related with the architecture x86_64 except on cmake pointing to python proto_buf and bzip libraries. I'm trying to deploy without having to install opencv on the host machine, I'd like to just take whatever libraries necessary that were built in the computer that I developed my project and copy them to new machine. At least you can just deploy a project in Windows having just the opencv310.dll and some other files to take care of the deployment without having to install opencv.